# Validity of a P-value when quality control fails

Tags: hypothesis-testing, p-value

Suppose one performed an experiment, which was a bad one - judged by quality control measures. Can one still rely on the p-values generated by statistical tests on this data?

As a specific case, suppose it is reasonable to think of the experiment's failure as causing a reduction in the amount of data generated - in a random manner. In such a case, since it is reasonable to think of the generated data as a random subset of the data of a good experiment, it seems that the significant results would still be valid. Is that wrong, from a statistical point of view, and why if so?

Comment: Please spell out QC. I'm not familiar with that acronym. Also, not everyone who reads CrossValidated is a native speaker of English, and acronyms can be particularly tricky.  Quality control???

Comment: @PeterFlom edited. Indeed QC=Quality Control

Comment: What does it mean to "rely on the p-values"? You should almost never make inferences on the basis of just a p-value.

Comment: What is "an experiment's failure"? How would you be confident that any "reduction in data generated" is random?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The validity of p-values calculated from hypothesis tests rely on assumptions about your experimental design. If your experiment does not meet these assumptions, you shouldn’t trust the p-value. For example, experiments assume data is a random sample drawn from the target population and that experimental units are randomly assigned to treatment and control groups. There are other assumptions, including [SUTVA](https://bookdown.org/paul/applied-causal-analysis/sutva1.html).

Your test is making assumptions as well. For example, a t-test assumes independent observations and may assume homogenous variance in the treatment and control groups. The validity of your p-value relies on these assumptions as well.

If indeed your “bad” experiment means you only have data for a random subset of experimental units, the p-value may remain technically valid. However, I question how this would happen and if you’re only making this assumption for convenience.

In summary, rigorous experimental design is essential for producing meaningful p-values. A p-value is not a substitute for addressing flaws in your experimental design.

Answer (score 1):

Edit: The following answer is only about the specific example of yours. The question whether the p-value stays valid for your research endeavor given any deviation is most certainly no. However, it depends on what exactly went wrong and to what degree, so the question cannot be answered in generality.

---

Statistically, the p-value is valid in the sense that you can expect to see the effect you observed or a more extreme one in "p-value" fraction of cases in a similar setting, i.e. with more draws of that size of that population without changing other parameters.

The more interesting question is to evaluate whether or not that still fits your needs, which is not necessarily a statistical question. Suppose you have two production lines, one of those with a new procedure, the other with the old one. You want to find out whether the new one is better than the old one. Now you do not just want to compare the raw numbers of "correct parts" (or whatever it is you are analyzing) but you want to do a statistical test to compare procedures incorporating sampling variability. There was a sample size you aimed for, that means you determined the sample size needed in some way beforehand. Ideally this included reflection about the error rates you decided to accept for your test (Type 1 error: concluding that there is a difference when there isn't, Type 2: concluding that there is no difference when there really is one). Together with your expected/desired effect size, this determines the sample size you need for that test. So when you then run the experiment in that way, you get a meaningful test with these (long-run) error rates.

The problem now is that if you reduce your sample size, with everything else being equal, there is no way to keep these error rates the same. So if you still want to use your data for that test, at least one of these error rates need to or will be changed, i.e. less power if you keep the significance threshold the same, or a higher prob. for type 1 errors with a higher significance threshold, but equal power. Which of those it is and if that is still acceptable, is a decision you have to make, and it is best done before you observe the p-value so you are not tempted to decide what to do based on your p-value, which could invalidate the error rates.

Comment: You are correct to say that a reduction in sample size below what was planned would reduce the power of an experiment, but it is not necessary to have a pre-determined sample size for the p-value from a significance test to be 'valid' in any sense. P-values and error rates are quite different things. See this paper for a full explanation: https://link.springer.com/chapter/10.1007/164_2019_286

Comment: Yes, this is why I first stated that the p-value is statistically valid, and then went on to explain why this still does not mean that you can draw the same conclusions from a changed experiment. And the power does not necessarily change, only when you decide to keep alpha the same.

Comment: You are a not entirely wrong, but you seem to be thinking only in terms of the global error rates, and not in terms of local evidence. That's why I suggested that you read a bit more. Really, it's a good paper and I am confident that it will help you see statistical testing and scientific inference more clearly.

Comment: Yes, that is correct, but I do it on purpose. In my eyes global error rates and local evidence mingle objective and subjective interpretations of probability and this does not lead to a coherent framework for inference. This is because under the objective interpretation individual events cannot have probabilities (they are just what they are because they are objective), but probabilities apply to collectives. Thus, individual hypotheses do not have a probability either, they are just true or false, so it is incoherent to say one hypothesis is more likely to be true than another.

Comment: This is why we can only talk about the probability of events given hypothesis (long-run frequencies), but not the probability of a hypothesis given an event/data (because the conditioning on data does not change whether the hypothesis is true or not). So p-values give you exactly that, the long-run frequency for extreme data, which is the probability of obtaining evidence, but not the evidence itself. So p-values are not a (good) measure of evidence, even though they appear to be in many (maybe most) cases.

Comment: I think that you should read the linked paper. Local evidence does not require a subjective interpretation of probability. Also, no error rate-preferring method that I read can give coherent inference unless you are uninterested in what the data say about the hypothesis of interest. Again, read the paper.

Comment: When you write "The P-value of a significance test is local because it is an index of the evidence in this data against" H0, it seems that p-values = evidence. But they are not, they are probs. of obtaining evidence, and this is not the same. Based on obj. probability, you cannot get around that individual hypotheses do not have probabilities, so you cannot use the framework to evaluate what "the data say about the hypothesis". You are right that the framework becomes incoherent when you change that, but in my eyes this is not a good solution. You need to switch to subj. probabilities.

Comment: I never say that p-values are the evidence. They index the evidence by pointing one to one to likelihood functions. You are correct that evidence does not have a scale of probability, but it does have a scale of likelihood (ratios). See this for details: https://arxiv.org/pdf/1311.0081.pdf

Comment: So your argument (in a nutshell) is that the likelihood ratio stays the same when you randomly change your sample size?

Comment: ??? I do not know what you mean. Which argument? It sounds unlikely. Which likelihood ratio? Why would I randomly change sample size?

Comment: Sorry for the sharp turn back and the neglected context - this was related to the original question in this thread, where the sample size got randomly reduced, unplanned. I understood your initial comments in a way that one could (or maybe even should) still use the p-value for local evidence here. Now I wanted to know how that would work, and I assumed after your last comment that this is done via the likelihood (ratios).

Comment: A different sample size will yield a different likelihood function. Even if the p-value is the same. That p-value will point to ('index') each of those likelihood functions because the p-value and test and sample size are all necessary parts of specifying the likelihood function. Do not think in terms of a singular likelihood ratio, but use the whole function. You know, it's complicated and is rarely explored. Too much for comments here. You should read the paper.